# Recursion and if statement only returns the negative value

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, recursion, multidimensional-array

So this question is really 2 questions in 1 relating to an assignment. I have to make a program that reads a map from a file containing land, water, sandbag, and house tiles into a 2d array and GUI displaying the map.

When a button is pressed the water tiles spread to all land and house tiles that are touching it (horizontal, vertical, and diagonal) and then displays a message that tells you if the house was flooded or not.

This has to be done via a recursive method, I have a program that works for the most part utilizing  8 `if` statements which I believe is incredibly inefficient and also doesn't really fit the assignment requirements. How could I make this recursive?

My second problem which I think is related to the way I approached the flooding question is that my method that checks if the house is still standing always displays the house was flooded message even if the house was standing.

I've been trying to fix this for days, any insight would be much appreciated. (I also previously had a problem where having `for` loops in my `checkForHouse` method would cause my program to freeze and have to be closed through task manager, it randomly stopped doing this even though I didn't change anything not sure if that helps).

```
public static void Flood(JLabel[][] labelArray, JPanel panel) {
    //Timer that allows the GUI to update slowly so progression can be seen
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        boolean running = true;
        while(running) {
            //Checks through the entire array to find water tiles 
            for (int i = 0; i < labelArray.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < labelArray[0].length; j++) {
                    if (labelArray[i][j].getText().equals("W")) {
                        if(i > 0 && (labelArray[i-1][j].getText().equals("L") || labelArray[i-1][j].getText().equals("H"))) {//Checks the tile left of the water tile
                            labelArray[i-1][j].setText("W");
                            labelArray[i-1][j].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                        else if(j > 0 && (labelArray[i][j-1].getText().equals("L") ||labelArray[i][j-1].getText().equals("H"))) {//Checks the tile above the water tile
                            labelArray[i][j-1].setText("W");
                            labelArray[i][j-1].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                        else if(i < labelArray.length-1 && (labelArray[i+1][j].getText().equals("L") || labelArray[i+1][j].getText().equals("H"))){//Checks the tile to the right of the water tile
                            labelArray[i+1][j].setText("W");
                            labelArray[i+1][j].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                        else if(j < labelArray[0].length-1 && (labelArray[i][j+1].getText().equals("L") || labelArray[i][j+1].getText().equals("H"))) {//Checks the tile below the water tile
                            labelArray[i][j+1].setText("W");
                            labelArray[i][j+1].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                            }       
                        else if(j < labelArray[0].length-1 && i < labelArray.length-1 && (labelArray[i+1][j+1].getText().equals("L") || labelArray[i+1][j+1].getText().equals("H"))) {//Checks the tile to the bottom right of the water tile
                            labelArray[i+1][j+1].setText("W");
                            labelArray[i+1][j+1].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                        else if(j > 0 && i > 0 && (labelArray[i-1][j-1].getText().equals("L") || labelArray[i-1][j-1].getText().equals("H"))) {//Checks the tile to the top left of the water tile
                            labelArray[i-1][j-1].setText("W");
                            labelArray[i-1][j-1].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                        else if(j > 0 && i < labelArray.length-1 && (labelArray[i+1][j-1].getText().equals("L") || labelArray[i+1][j-1].getText().equals("H"))) {//Checks the tile to the top right of the water tile
                            labelArray[i+1][j-1].setText("W");
                            labelArray[i+1][j-1].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                        else if(j < labelArray[0].length-1 && i > 0 && (labelArray[i-1][j+1].getText().equals("L") || labelArray[i-1][j+1].getText().equals("H"))) {//Checks the tile to the bottom left of the water tile
                            labelArray[i-1][j+1].setText("W");
                            labelArray[i-1][j+1].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            running = false;
            checkForHouse(labelArray);
        }
    }
    };
    new Timer(250, taskPerformer).start();
}

    public static void checkForHouse (JLabel[][] labelArray) {
    for (int r =0; r<labelArray.length; r++) {
        for (int c =0;c<labelArray[0].length; c++) {
            if(labelArray[r][c].getText().equals("H")) {
                textArea.setText(safeHouse);
            }
            else {
                textArea.setText(floodedHouse);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Updated based on comment

1. water can flow all the way to boundary
2. water can flow to adjacent land or adjacent house and they become water
3. water can not flow to adjacent sandbag
4. based on point 3, water surrounded on all sides by sandbag will not flow

### traverse recursively from every newly filled land or house

1. using 2 for loop, iterate over all the cells
2. for any cell that has 'W', call another function
3. the another function will recursively update any adjacent land or house

```java
final int[] x = new int[] {-1, -1, -1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1};
final int[] y = new int[] {-1,  0,  1, -1,  1, -1   0,  1}; 

final char HOUSE = 'H'
final char LAND = 'L'; 
final char WATER = 'W';
final char WATERED_HOUSE = 'A';
final char WATERED_LAND = 'B'; 

final char SANDBAG = 'S'; // not used and is not needed

void process(char[][] input) {
  for (int row = 0; row < input.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < input[row].length; col++) {
      if (input[row][col] == WATER) {
        processNeighbor(input, row, col);
      }
    }
  }
  // if a cell is WATERED_HOUSE, then update text (if not done in processNeighbor function)
  for (int row = 0; row < input.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < input[row].length; col++) {
      if (input[row][col] == WATERED_HOUSE) {
        // set text
      }
      // if needed for WATERED_HOUSE and WATERED_LAND, 
      // change back to WATER and LAND respectively
    }
  }
}

void processNeighbor(char[][] input, final int row, final int col) {
  for (int adj = 0; adj < adjCount; adj++) {
    final int hor = col + x[adj];
    final int ver = row + y[adj];

    // stop recursion if neighbor is a not any one of house or land.
    if (!isValid(input, ver, hor) || !(input[ver][hor] == LAND || input[ver][hor] == HOUSE)) {
      continue;
    }

    // modify state to help recursion to end
    // if modification is not allowed, then maintain separate visited state
    if (input[ver][hor] == HOUSE) {
      input[ver][hor] = WATERED_HOUSE;
      // note: can set flooded here or in a separate loop later
    } else if (input[ver][hor] == LAND) {
      input[ver][hor] = WATERED_LAND;
    }

    // process any unprocessed neighbor recursively
    processNeighbor(input, ver, hor);
  }
}

// check whether given cell is within grid
boolean isValid(char[][] input, final int row, final int col) {
  return row >= 0 && row < input.length && col >= 0 && col < input[row].length;
}
```

### Original

This following logic assumes that water will flow only to 1 adjacent tile. Is that a valid assumption?

#### separation of logic and bfs

1. Use additional labels. 'A' can represent watered house.
2. using additional label simplifies the code and avoid forward modifications of 'H' to 'W', which the subsequent iterations will consider as 'W' incorrectly (while its actually a 'H' with 'W' and not initially a 'W')
3. 2 loops in another outer function which calls another function if 'W' is seen at the cell
4. the second function will run a for loop with directions and updates the adjancent locations if they are 'H'
5. finally run one more 2 loop and change all 'A' to 'W' and change color
6. you can add similar check for land also

```java
// can make this an unmodifiable list to avoid accidental modification
//                         LU   L  LD   U   D  RU   R   RD
final int[] x = new int[] {-1, -1, -1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1};
final int[] y = new int[] {-1,  0,  1, -1,  1, -1   0,  1}; 
final int adjCount = 8;
final char WATER = 'W';
final char HOUSE = 'H'
final char WATERED_HOUSE = 'A'; 

int process(char[][] input) {
  int count = 0; // this is just to track and for any optimization

  // initial processing to process cells adjacent to water
  for (int row = 0; row < input.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < input[row].length; col++) {
      if (WATER == input[row][col]) {
        count += processAdjacents(input, row, col);
      }
    }
  }

  final int modified = count;

  // second round to set watered house to water and color
  for (int row = 0; row < input.length; row++) {
    // if needed can use count == 0 to break;
    for (int col = 0; col < input[row].length; col++) {
      // if needed can use count == 0 to break;

      if (WATERED_HOUSE == input[row][col]) {
        input[row][col] = WATER;
        // set background color also
        count--;
      }
    }  
  }
  return modified;
}

// process adjacent cells of water cell
int processAdjacents(char[][] input, final int row, final int col) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int adj = 0; adj < adjCount; adj++) {
    final int hor = col + x[adj];
    final int ver = row + y[adj];
    
    if (isValid(input, ver, hor) && HOUSE == input[ver][hor]) {
      input[ver][hor] = WATERED_HOUSE;
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

// check whether given cell is within grid
boolean isValid(char[][] input, final int row, final int col) {
  return row >= 0 && row < input.length && col >= 0 && col < input[row].length;
}
```

#### Disclaimer

1. Untested code and typed in SO
2. Did not use DFS
3. land not handled

Comment: No, I believe it asks to change all applicable water tiles at once meaning  you have to identify which tiles need to be changed and then change them -> repeat multiple times until all applicable tiles are changed hence the recursion, problem is I don't know how to do that.